# Add affiliations to the authors' name

Tags: article, affiliation

I am using the `\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,a4paper,final]{book}` to write an article. How can I add the affiliation to the author's name ?

Now, I'am using overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/10139084dvxtzsfkhcbf. In `main.tex` include a lot packages.

I am using `\inputarticle[111.111]{ivanov}{I.\,O. Name, I.\,O. Name}` which errors occur. Or I'm not right?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How is the affiliation supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something simple like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,a4paper,final]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{How to Structure a LaTeX Document}
\author{Andrew Roberts \\ Where I am From}
\date{December 2004}
\maketitle
\chapter{Preface}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
\backmatter
\chapter{Last note}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The "Where I am From" can be changed to "University of Misery", "University of Reading" or wherever you are from.

Comment: Error: Runaway argument?
|\@empty \protect \protect {
Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@@ProtectSpacesFi was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par

Comment: What options do you send to {hyperref}? I don't get the same error.

Comment: I don''t know what package \inputarticle is from. I can't seem to find it on google.